# Sum a range of cells based on condition

Tags: excel

I have a sheet like below:

[image: Sheet]

I want to be able to SUM the Value fields if there is a tick next to that person's name, you will see each name has a value and if they attended that week and have a tick then include this value in the sum. I want to populate the Collected Field to show how much was collected that week.

I have tried SUMIF on a range but with no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMIF should work if you want to do it for each week, e.g. in C22 copied across

`=SUMIF(C5:C19,"x",$B5:$B19)`

replace the "x" with the specific character you are using to get the tick